# IndexedDB vs SQlite for HTML5 Cordova Hybrid Mobile Application

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, indexeddb, hybrid-mobile-app, offline-caching

We are developing a hybrid mobile(ios/android) app(AngularJS,HTML5,Ionic) for an already existing cloud-based CRM. We want to have extensive offline data management capabilities which might include storing of large amount of data locally on the app itself. Also there will be periodic as well as on-demand syncing of data from the server to keep the local data up-to-date. My question is what kind of storage framework should be used at the mobile client side in this situation. Thanks in advance!